# Values skipped when serializing a simple class

Tags: vb.net, serialization

I have a simple class structure;

```
Public Class Country
    Public CountryCode As String = ""
End Class

Public Class AllCountries
    Inherits List(Of Country)
    Public name As String
End Class

Public MyAc As New AllCountries

Public Sub Serialize()
    Dim myC As New Country
    myC.CountryCode = "be"
    MyAc.Add(myC)
    MyAc.name = "yadda"
    Dim Serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(AllCountries))
    Using Target As New FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.CreateNew)
        Serializer.Serialize(Target, MyAc)
        Target.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

When I serialize this, the XML does not contain the 'name' field, and value;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfCountry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <Country>
     <CountryCode>be</CountryCode>
 </Country>
 </ArrayOfCountry>
```

If I remove the 'Inherits List(Of Country)' the name value is saved in the XML. But I don't know a way around this. Thanks

Comment: Do you need `Inherits List(Of Country)` or would `Public Countries As New List(Of Country)` work too? The latter also avoids the name of the `<ArrayOfCountry>` tag.

Comment: Try adding the <Serializable> attribute to your classes.